# Metastock to MQL4 conversion

Tags: mql4

I would like to know how I can use the Ref() function of metastock in MQL4.
Ref() in metastock is used to take the previous values of the given data array.
for example:

`Ref(C,-1)`

gives the value of previous day's close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iClose(_Symbol,PERIOD_D1,1)` for close. In Mql4 0 means the current candle, and increases to the left, so -1 in your case becomes 1; this is true when accessing candle data. For regular arrays, e.g., obtained by `CopyBuffer` or looping, array indexes are 0 to `ArraySize()-1`